# Issue with Google OAuth2 in Kubernetes: EAI_AGAIN Error When Sending Emails

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, nginx, gmail-api

I'm encountering an issue with Google OAuth2 in my Kubernetes environment when trying to send emails using the Gmail API.

The setup works fine locally, but fails in Kubernetes, giving an EAI_AGAIN error.

This might be related to my NGINX ingress configuration, but I'm not certain. Here's the error message:

```
Error obtaining SMTP token: GaxiosError: request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN oauth2.googleapis.com
```

This is my ingress configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: auth.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/auth/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
    - host: products.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/products/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: products-srv
                port:
                  number: 3001
```

```
[mail] Error obtaining SMTP token: GaxiosError: request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN oauth2.googleapis.com
[mail]     at Gaxios._request (/app/node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts:183:13)
[mail]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[mail]     at async OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:190:19)
[mail]     at async OAuth2Client.refreshAccessTokenAsync (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:224:19)
[mail]     at async OAuth2Client.getAccessTokenAsync (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:253:23) {
[mail]   config: {
[mail]     method: 'POST',
[mail]     url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
[mail]     data: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.',
[mail]     headers: {
[mail]       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
[mail]       'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/9.6.0',
[mail]       'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/21.6.0'
[mail]     },
[mail]     paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
[mail]     body: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.',
[mail]     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
[mail]     responseType: 'unknown',
[mail]     errorRedactor: [Function: defaultErrorRedactor]
[mail]   },
[mail]   response: undefined,
[mail]   error: FetchError: request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN oauth2.googleapis.com
[mail]       at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501:11)
[mail]       at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
[mail]       at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)
[mail]       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:492:9)
[mail]       at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
[mail]       at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
[mail]       at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
[mail]       at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
[mail]       at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
[mail]     type: 'system',
[mail]     errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
[mail]     code: 'EAI_AGAIN'
[mail]   },
[mail]   code: 'EAI_AGAIN'
[mail] }
```

Context:

My application is running in a Kubernetes cluster.
I use NGINX as an ingress controller.
The email sending functionality works locally but not in the cluster.
Questions:

How can I troubleshoot and resolve the EAI_AGAIN error in this Kubernetes setup?
Could this be related to NGINX ingress settings? If so, what specific configurations should I check or modify?

Thank you for your support